# Select records on a specific day mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I currently query my DB like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM app2 WHERE appdate =< CURDATE()";
```

What i want to do is search for records that are 30 days old only.
Not the last 30days , but on the 30th day.

Comment: you want the records for the 30th date.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATE()` and `DATE_SUB()`. `DATE(appdate)` ignores the time part if handling datetimes.

```
SELECT * FROM app2 
WHERE DATE(appdate) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `date_sub` function as

```
SELECT * FROM app2 WHERE appdate = date_sub(curdate(),interval 30 day);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM app2 WHERE appdate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
```